# how to generate Html.ActionLink with icon

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET MVC, and have a problem, how generate code with `Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
<a href="~/Views/Home/Create.cshtml" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
    <span>
        <strong>Create</strong>
    </span>            
</a>
```

please.

Comment: I've using this, but cannot understand how add i tag

@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Home", null, new {@class= "btn btn-primary"})

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink()` only supports plain-text links.

You should use `<a href="@Url.Action(...)">` for more-complex links.

Answer (score 49):

I wanted to add to SLaks answer.

Using `<a href="@Url.Action(...)">` with what user2567619 wanted.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Home")" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
    <span>
        <strong>Create</strong>
    </span>            
</a>
```

I think it's worth mentioning that `@Url.Action` can take it's parameters like this:

```
@Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName)
```

Whereas `@Html.ActionLink` can take it's parameters like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
```

It may be pretty obvious, but I thought it was worth noting.

#### Edit

As Peck_conyon noted, for both `@Url.Action` and `@Html.ActionLink`, these are just one of the ten different overload methods. 
For documentation on `UrlHelper.Action`, look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx).
For documentation on `LinkEtensions.ActionLink`, look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: What you have mentioned is just one of the 10 overloads of this method. There are 9 other ways that @Html.ActionLink can be used in MVC5

Comment: @Peck_conyon Thanks for the comment. I've tried to update it accordingly. I wanted to show a simple example of both showing the `actionName` and `controllerName` parameters, but there are 10 overloads for both which is worth noting.

Answer (score 6):

Simple as this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action", null, new {@class="btn btn-info fa fa-pencil" })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","",new { @class= "btn btn-primary" })
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irKQG.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Where is the icon?

Answer (score 3):

If it's in the Layout page, you can use this, I think it may help:

```html
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Login", "Index", new { Controller = "Login", Area = "Security" }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" })</li>
```

or like this for a action_link:

```html
    <p>
    @Html.ActionLink(" Create New", "Add", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" })</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put like this:
take the help of google icons. just paste the style tag and libraries into your template like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Roun**strong text**ded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kdam+Thmor+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .material-symbols-rounded {
        font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 0, 'wght' 400, 'GRAD' 0, 'opsz' 48
    }
</style>
```

use the above libraries like this:

```
<a href="Home/Edit/@item.id" class="material-symbols-rounded">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add Stock", "Create", null, new { @class = " fa fa-plus link-dark rounded " })
```

**Add Stock** is String Link Text
**Create** String Action Name
**null** Object routevalues
**new { @class = " fa fa-plus link-dark rounded " }** is Object html Attributes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question was made almost 10 years ago. Now, using ASP .NET Core 7, the code to get it is the next:

```html
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
  <strong>Create</strong>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This example may help you.

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Controller", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn
                 btn-success btn-circle fa fa-plus-circle", title = "Confirm" })
```

this way you will have an icon without the text.