# How to add icon to ActionLink in MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have ActionLink :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName",
             new { @class = "SomeStyle" })
```

Now I want to replace the "Text" with icon I have it in my solution

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144443/1745795 may be will help

Answer (score 0):

Use `url.Action`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")">
        <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
       .....        
    </a>
```